# When a layout is not explicity declared, what is the default layout for an Activity?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, default

I had written a simple Hello World application with a single Activity.

Class:

```
public class HelloWorld extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.helloworld);
    }

}
```

helloworld.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/textview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:text="@string/hello"/>
```

I have required resources and 'AndroidManifest.xml' in place, the application is running fine.

In 'View Hierarchy window' of 'hierarchyviewer' tool, I notice that TextView widget's parent is FrameLayout whose parent is LinearLayout (for brevity, I had cut only required screen shot). Screen shot:

[image: View Hierarchy window's screen shot]

In my 'helloworld.xml', I had not declared FrameLayout as parent for TextView widget. Please help me understand:
1. In general, how runtime decides on a layout if it is not explicitly declared in layout resource (xml file)?
2. In the diagram, why LinearLayout is parent of FrameLayout?

Thanks much in advance.

Answer (score 3):

With the help of a hint from link posted by Vikram Bodicherla and some effort, I found answers to my questions.
The answers to my questions lie in Android 3.0 release - "when the application is installed on a device running Android 3.0 or greater, 
the system applies the holographic theme to each activity, and thus, each activity includes the Action Bar.", from documentation.

1 In general, how runtime decides on a layout if it is not explicitly declared in layout resource (xml file)?
- See below answer.

2 In the diagram, why LinearLayout is parent of FrameLayout?
- LineraLayout divides UI into two sections - top and bottom which represent ActionBar and activity's UI (components, other than 
  ActionBar components) respectively. Bottom section has FrameLayout which is an apt layout to contain any layout. So, if you do 
  not explicitly specify any layout in your layout resource, such as mine (see above -  helloworld.xml), components will always be placed 
  in FrameLayout. If you declare ANY layout, say GridLayout or even LinearLayout or FrameLayout, it will still be included in FrameLayout which will be included in LinearLayout. This also explains why "...the parent of an activity's content view is always a FrameLayout." from link posted by Vikram Bodicherla.

@Vikram Bodicherla - I had given a point for your link post, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

If a set contentview is not called than ALL views that are found in the R.java will be null. Specifically this is because views don't get created until setContentView(xx) is called. There is no "default layout."

These are the options available to configuring a layout in an `Activity`:

```
void     setContentView(int layoutResID)
Set the activity content from a layout resource.

void     setContentView(View view)
Set the activity content to an explicit view.

void     setContentView(View view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params)
Set the activity content to an explicit view.
```

Upon the calling of these one of these methods, you will instantiate your views onto your activity, so when retrieving them from the R.java they will be non-null.